# Extract a dictionary of substring in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I have files of the kind:

```
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30), (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39), (40), (41), (42), (43), (51), (52), (53), (54), (55), (56), (57), (58), (62), (63), (64), (65), (66), (67), (68), (69), (70), (71), (72), (73), (74) Use method number 1. (7), (8), (9), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (59), (60), (61) Use method number 2. (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49), (50) Use method number 3.
```

I would like to build a dictionary containing the numbers between parentheses and link them to the sentences of the type: "`Use method number #`". So, in this case:

```
1,2,3,4,5...74 --> Use method number 1.
7,8,9,19....61 --> Use method number 2.
```

Currently I am building a complex while that reads regexs (`^ *\([0-9]+\)`), extracts each number, deletes the coincidence and starts again until regex is not found and then extracts the sentence. But this is quite poor in performance and tedious to maintain.

Have you got any suggestions on how to improve this through more compact methods other than the `while do`?

I am not bothered by the dictionary structure, do not consider it right now if it does not imply modifying the method.

**EDIT. ADDING REAL DATA STRING:**

(12), (13), (14), (15) P.S.: 3 días en cultivo de invernadero. Efectuar un máximo de 6 aplicaciones por
                       campaña a intervalos de 7 días utilizando un volumen máximo de caldo de 600 l/Ha. y un máximo de
                       7,5 Kg de cobre inorgánico por campaña.
                       (28) Tratamiento en otoño, pulverizando hasta una altura de 1,5 m.
                       (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49), (50), (51) Efectuar sólo tratamientos desde la cosecha hasta la
                       floración, limitando la aplicación a 1200 l. de caldo/Ha. y un máximo de 3 aplicaciones por campaña
                       (con un intervalo de tratamientos de 14 días) y un máximo de 7,5 Kg. de cobre inorgánico/Ha.por
                       campaña.

Comment: Are there line breaks after `Use method number ..` in the input data?

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that the sentence can be longer than the one I have used for the example and can contain multiple '.'.

Comment: Then update your question with more representative data.

Comment: @Kankamuso Yes, you need to show real input data..

Comment: Done. Sorry guys. Tried to simplify and did it too much.

Comment: Try to edit the edition (lol) and give the proper format. Now it is a bit unclear how it looks like (is it multiline?)

Comment: @fedorqui, it is a single line. Quite a long string. How should I edit it to make it clearer?

Comment: Ah ok, it is a single line. The problem gets bigger, since there is no general pattern here apart from a string after the last appearance of `(digit)`. It would be better if you can get this text differently, for example having each block in different lines, one line for the digits and another one for the text.

Comment: I am afraid then that the only solution is the one I am using now :-(. The text comes in this format and is not under my control to change it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kankamuso Can I assume the following is true?: A sequence of numbers separated by a colon will contain at least 3 items: `1,2,3` are ok, `1,2` is not. Also meaning the sentence(s) will not contain 3 numbers (or more) separated by a comma. If this is true you can use the following `sed` command:  `sed -r 's/( *\(|\))//g;s/\.([0-9]+,){2}/.\n\1/g'`

Comment: Or if you need that `-->` use `sed -r 's/( *\(|\))//g;s/(([0-9]+,){2,}[0-9]+ )/\n\1--> /g;s/^\n//'`

Comment: @hek2mgl I think the problem was ill-posed. Sorry. I did not describe it correctly. The number of (#) is undefined and can go from 1 to N. Then, the sentence is arbitrary, but DOES NOT contain a (#) construct (it can however have something like '(Hi this is a string 1)', including numbers, but not just a number).

Comment: @Kankamuso Then you would need to fix the data source itself. No chance for after-processing if the data follows no-rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/( *\(|\))//g;s/\./\n/g' input.txt
```

This assumes that your input file does not contain line breaks. If it contains line breaks the command needs to get modified a bit.

**Explanation:**

The first command `s/( *\(|\))//g` removes the parentheses and additional whitespace. The second command `s/\./\n/g` adds a newline after a dot.

---

Oh I missed that you want to add an additional `-->`. If you really need that, the second sed commands needs to get modified:

```
sed -r 's/( *\(|\))//g;s/U[^.]+\./--> \0\n/g' input.txt
```

Now the second command searches for the sequence `U --> until a dot` and prepends a `-->` plus adds the newline after the dot.

**Output:**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,10,...,74 --> Use method number 1.
7,8,9,19,20,21,22,23,59,60,61 --> Use method number 2.
44,45,46,47,48,49,50 --> Use method number 3.
```

---

One another thing: The above commands adds an additional newline at the end of output. You can suppress that by adding a third sed command `s/\n$//` which removes the additional new line before the end of the output:

```
sed -r 's/( *\(|\))//g;s/U[^.]+\./--> \0\n/g;s/\n$//' input.txt
```

Comment: I have just added a comment I forgot to mention and that it is important. Sentences after numbers can be more complex and include multiple sub-sentences separated by'.'. It can also include parentheses, but with sentences within it, not just a number.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an idiomatic gnu awk solution:

```
awk -v RS="Use method number [0-9]."
    -v OFS=" --> "
    'NF{gsub(/\s*|\(|\)/, ""); print $0, RT}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ awk -v RS="Use method number [0-9]." -v OFS=" --> " 'NF{gsub(/\s*|\(|\)/, ""); print $0, RT}' a
1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74 --> Use method number 1.
7,8,9,19,20,21,22,23,59,60,61 --> Use method number 2.
44,45,46,47,48,49,50 --> Use method number 3.
```

#### Explanation

- `-v RS="Use method number [0-9]."` set the record separator to the string "Use method number X.`, X being a digit.
- `-v OFS=" --> "` set the print separator.
- `NF{gsub(/\s*|\(|\)/, ""); print $0, RT}` main code
  -- `NF {}` if there is at least one field, proceed.
  -- `gsub(/\s*|\(|\)/, "")` remove all spaces, `(` and `)` from the string.
  -- `print $0, RT` print the replaced string together with the record separator that was used ("Use method number X."). Using `RT` instead of `RS` so that we catch the value of the specific `X` used in the string.

From `man awk`:

> **RT**
>
> The record terminator.  Gawk sets RT to the input text that matched
>   the character or regular expression specified by RS.

Answer (score 1):

you can very intuitively do it with an `ed` script,

```
:: ed.script ::
# first you split your data in multiple lines
,s/\(\(([0-9]*), \)*([0-9]*)\)/\
\1\
/g

# then for each matching line with numbers, you remove unwanted chars
# and append " --> " to the next line
,g/\(\(([0-9]*), \)*([0-9]*)\)/\
s/[)( ]//g\
a\
 -->\
.

# and finally you join lines
,g/^ -->/-1,+1j

# save if you want
w
```

Then you launch it with the following command:

```
cat ed.script | ed -s file.txt
```

that was the part intuitive... and it works with your sample data.

Comment: Interesting way to obtain the sequence of numbers. Thanks!